# Powershell Invoke-Command with arbitrary ScriptBlock

Tags: powershell, window, winrm

I have the following command which executes successfully on a remote Windows server.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -UseSSL -SessionOption $sessionOptions -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock
 {Start-Service "Test Service"}
```

I am attempting to pass in the script block as a variable so that I can execute any arbitrary command on the particular server, but I can't seem to pass the ScriptBlock argument successfully. The code executes without any errors, but does not start the remote service.

```
$ScriptBlock = Start-Service "Test Service"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName -UseSSL -SessionOption $sessionOptions -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock
 {$args[0]} -ArgumentList $ScriptBlock
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the code in `{}` to define a scriptblock literal when assigning it to your `$ScriptBlock` variable, then pass that as the argument to the `-ScriptBlock` parameter:

```
$ScriptBlock = { Start-Service "Test Service" }

Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $ScriptBlock -ComputerName $ComputerName -UseSSL -SessionOption $sessionOptions -Credential $cred
```

Comment: That was it. Can't believe I overlooked that, thanks!